# Java Decompress a string compressed with zlib deflate

Tags: java, zlib, deflate

As the title says. How do you decompress a compressed string which was compressed with zlib deflate? What is the solid way of doing it with an explanation?

Answer (score 16):

Try this - it is a minimal working example:

```
package zlib.example;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream;

/**
 * Created by keocra on 08.10.15.
 */
public class Main {
    private final static String inputStr = "Hello World!";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Will zlib compress following string: " + inputStr);

        // will compress "Hello World!"
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DeflaterOutputStream dos = new DeflaterOutputStream(baos);
        dos.write(inputStr.getBytes());
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

        // at this moment baos.toByteArray() holds the compressed data of "Hello World!"

        // will decompress compressed "Hello World!"
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        InflaterInputStream iis = new InflaterInputStream(bais);

        String result = "";
        byte[] buf = new byte[5];
        int rlen = -1;
        while ((rlen = iis.read(buf)) != -1) {
            result += new String(Arrays.copyOf(buf, rlen));
        }

        // now result will contain "Hello World!"

        System.out.println("Decompress result: " + result);
    }
}
```

You should also easily be able to extend this example to compress/decompress files.

Hope it helps ;-)

Further readings:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.html

Comment: Please be more specific what you want to do. The example above is not bound to a specific string length. To be clear: Changing inputStr should be sufficient. If you want to tune the example you should also change the byte buffer (...new byte[5]) to i.e. new byte[1024].

Comment: what is the byte[] buf doing then?

Comment: I'm a little late to answer this ;-)  
byte[] buf = new byte[5]; initialize an empty byte array which is used as a buffer for reading from the input stream.   
iis.read(buf) then read max. 5 bytes from the input stream at once per round.  
Arrays.copyOf(buf, rlen) just greps the amount of bytes that were actually read.  
For instance assume you have 23 bytes in the input stream. Reading five bytes per round would lead to 4 rounds actually reading 5 bytes and the last round to reading 3 bytes. So in the last round we are only interested in 3 bytes from the buf object.