# How to decompress image in JavaScript that was compressed by MS Sql

Tags: javascript, zlib, reactjs.net

I have an SQL table with two Columns:

```sql
[filedata] [varbinary](max) NULL
[Compressed File Data] [varbinary](max) NULL
```

The [Compressed File Data] is populated with with `COMPRESS([filedata])`. I store an image byte array in `[filedata]`.

I have a react component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Config from 'config';
import { Gunzip, decompress } from 'zlib'
import "./Item.css";

class ItemList extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: 'React',
            apiData: [],
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        console.log('app mounted');
        /*global fetch */
        const tokenString = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
        const token = JSON.parse(tokenString);
        const encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(token.customerNumber);
        const response = await fetch(Config.apiUrl + `/api/Items?customerNumber=${encodedValue}`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json",
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.token
            }
        });
        
        const json = await response.json();
        console.log(json);
        this.setState({ itemList: json.$values });        
    }

    //DecompressImage(compressedImage) {
    //    const buffer = Buffer.from(`${compressedImage}`, 'base64');
    //    Gunzip(buffer, (err, buffer) => {
    //        if (err) {
    //            console.error('An error occurred:', err);                
    //        }
    //        console.log(buffer.toString());
    //        return buffer;
    //    });
    //}

    DecompressImage(compressedImage) {
        console.log(compressedImage);
        var response = new Uint8Array(compressedImage);
        var compressed = response.subarray(0, response.byteLength - 4);
        var gunzip = new Gunzip(compressed);
        var decompress = gunzip.decompress();
        console.log(decompress)
        return decompress;
    }


    render() {
        const items = this.state.itemList;

        return (
            <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item Number</th>
                        <th>Item Description</th>
                        <th>Item Image</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {items && items.map((item, index) =>
                        <tr key={index}>
                            <td>{item.itemNumber}</td>
                            <td>{item.itemDescription}</td>
                            <td><img className="fit-picture" src={"data:image/png;base64," + this.DecompressImage(item.imageData)} id={item.itemNumber + "Img"} alt={item.itemNumber} /></td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}
export default ItemList;
```

For the life of me I cannot get `DecompressImage(compressedImage)` working. This worked before I tried to use compressed data. The commented `DecompressImage(compressedImage)` returns nothing and no log entry. The second one has an error on decompress that decompress is undefigned.

I have tried code from: [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/zlib.html) or this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60797417/compress-string-in-sql-server-and-decompress-in-javascript) question.

Any help would be appreciated.

*nodejs version 14.17.1*

Comment: Why would you need to do this after the fact, instead of using DECOMPRESS in your server side query to mssql? You'd get the normal image data, which you can then send on to the client using transparent gzip compression (i.e. your server should sends all data to the client using gzip or brotli, already, and the networking part of the browser will unpack that so neither you, nor your code, ever need to worry about manually de/compressing anything)?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The API queries the sql server and retrieves the compressed image and then forwards it to react app still compressed. That is two trips across the wire. I could decompress at the API but why?

Comment: The first trip is not on significant wire, though, it's between two servers on hosts optimized for connectivity, both of which are almost certainly on fiber and capable of handling orders of magnitude more data without batting an eye than you could ever use. Unless you're _actually_ running into cost issues due to the volume of data you're pushing, getting the image from the database in decompressed format is just not the kind of thing you should be worrying about if it means you don't have codec incompatibility issues further down the line?

Comment: Note: it might still be an interesting question to get an authoritative answer to, but as a question about a real world implementation, this seems a prime example of premature optimization that you just don't need to worry about until you've scaled to millions and millions of transactions.

Comment: (And of course, note that it looks like you're simply using the wrong decoder, [various pages](https://www.google.com/search?q=mssql+decoding+binary+COMPRESS) explain that the binary COMPRESS/DECOMPRESS fields [use glib, not zlib](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4559/sql-server-2016-compress-and-decompress-functions/), so the bounty might have been a tad premature =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you're getting a Base64 string as input to `DecompressImage()`. The problem might be that you're getting a hex string when you want an ArrayBuffer or a Base64 string. A hex string over the wire is even more inefficient than the uncompressed data. If you're sure that you're actually using a Base64 string from the JSON, you convert to a Uint8Array and decompress it.

Now that you've ensured you have a base64 input, note that the NPM `zlib` library is outdated and yields very low performance compared to modern alternatives like [`pako`](https://github.com/nodeca/pako) or [`fflate`](https://github.com/101arrowz/fflate) (my own library). As `fflate` is both smaller and faster than `pako`, I'll use it for this answer. Here's how you might go about decompressing the data:

```js
// Install both fflate and base64-js for maximum speed
import * as b64 from 'base64-js';
import { gunzipSync } from 'fflate';
// This should replace DecompressImage
// Decompresses gzip + base64 to base64
function decompressToBase64(base64String) {
  const bytes = b64.toByteArray(base64String);
  const decompressed = gunzipSync(bytes);
  return b64.fromByteArray(decompressed);
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error in module `base64-js`. `TypeError: b64 is undefined` at `./ClientApp/node_modules/base64-js/index.js:23`. Version base64-js@1.5.1.

Comment: Make sure you got the imports right, maybe its `import b64 from 'base64-js` or `const b64 = require('b64-js');`.

Comment: Same error with the new import line `import b64 from 'base64-js'`

Comment: One of my Items had a null value for `imageData`. Added the null check and everything works.